# Sierra update - wont recognise external soundcard

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio

Recently updated to Sierra 10.12.3 on my early '11 macbook pro. Trying to use my external usb soundcard (Maplin HD 7.1 USB Sound Card - maplin.co.uk/p/maplin-hd-71-usb-sound-card-a01nc) because the headphone socket doesn't work, but it wont see the card. It doesnt require any drivers, is lit up to show it is getting power / cable working. I have also just repaired the disk. Any ideas?

Cheers,

T.

Comment: Please post the specific make and model of your USB sound device.

Comment: Maplin HD 7.1 USB Sound Card  -  http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/maplin-hd-71-usb-sound-card-a01nc. @jimmy0x52

Comment: Looking at the support pages at Maplin, there are sadly no drivers available for MacOS. Are you actually using this for full 7.1 audio, or only as a stereo headphone jack? If the latter, there are many inexpensive USB > 3.5mm sound devices, some quite esoteric and expensive. I had use of one of these [Behringer devices](http://m.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Computer-Audio/Audio-Interfaces/UCA222/p/P0A31) for a few weeks this past summer. Worked like a charm. Very clean. Disclaimer: Satisfied Behringer user. No financial ties.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Q&A for the sound card you mentioned (check the "Questions" tab on the linked website in the comment to the original question) you'll see the first question is about the availability of Mac drivers and the manufacturer response states that none are available.

Looks like your best option is to find a different USB sound solution or get your logic board repaired.

Edit: aha I forgot about SIP. Sierra broke a bunch of driverless stuff with SIP. There are ramifications for disabling it, but if you want to try it [check out this Reddit post.](https://www.reddit.com/r/WeAreTheMusicMakers/comments/54m93p/mac_os_sierra_update_solution_to_not_detected/)

Comment: I've been using it for over a year with no drivers required and no problems at all. Hence why i don't understand it suddenly won't be picked up after this update @jimmy0x52

Comment: It could have been a fluke but the technician on the site says - as of 17 days ago - that there are no Mac drivers. You're likely not going to get a better answer than from a tech who actually works there.

Comment: Ah. thats a shame. Thanks for your help. considering a time machine backup to save myself £50 + on another one

Comment: There are plenty on Amazon for under $10 USD. I'm sure you can find something cheaper for basic sound! If you want something really nice I like the Fiio e10k but it'll set you back about $75 USD.

Comment: Thomas see my edit